# Apache 301 redirect

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf, 301-redirect

I have inherited a server with a couple of domains on it. The website was reworked within the last two years and I am trying to oblige a request by staff to get a redirect to work properly (if it can given the default structure).

So right now on the server I have a redirect that takes every 301 and dumps it onto the front page of the website.

```
RedirectMatch /(.) http://www.example.com
```

This has worked well for most of the old URL's coming in from various websites containing the old liking structure.

However, now a staff member wants a single URL which is somewhat widely used to be redirected to it's proper place.

Redirect /new/research/Exp_Rese_Disc/Asia/example.shtml http://example.com/asia/

Is this possible without killing the all encompassing 301 redirect?

To have a general RedirectMatch /(.) redirect as well as a singular redirect?

As of right now it is not seeming to let me. Any ideas, thoughts or examples are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider switching to RewriteConf/RewriteRule pairs, it's easier to control the flow of logic.

For instance:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_URI) ^/new/research/example.shtml$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/asia [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %(REQUEST_URI) /(.)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com [R=302]

#Drop the www
RewriteCond %(HTTP_HOST) !^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com$1 [R=301]
```

or something along those lines... Apache has [several](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html) [good](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) [references](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) on it.